# Lista con elementos repetidos en haskell

Tags: lista, haskell, repetidos

Necesito resolver un ejercicio con haskell, debo hacer una función
`reps :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]` que lo que hace es dada una lista nos regresa otra lista de pares ordenados donde la primer entrada corresponde a un elemento de la lista y la segunda entrada corresponde al número de veces que se repite el elemento en la lista, por ejemplo:

Recibimos esta lista `[11, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 5]` y nos regresa `[(11,1),(1,2),(3,4),(4,1),(5,2),(9,2),(2,1)]`

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Un modo de resolverlo sería creando una partición de manera recursiva:

```hs
import Data.List (partition )

reps :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
reps [] = []
reps (x:xs) = (x, 1 + length ys) : reps zs
  where (ys,zs) = partition (==x) xs
```